# Elementary Number Theory

Tags: nt.number-theory

Assume we have a free ring $S$ of rank 2 and $K= S \otimes Q$. Now if we define an equivalent relation similar to the case $S=O_{K}$ then is it true that the $S$-ideal classes form a group ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then no. Take $S = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{8}]$. Let $I = \langle 2 \rangle$ and let $J = \langle 2, \sqrt{8} \rangle$. Then $I \neq J$, but $IJ = J^2$. The integral closure condition shows up in number theory precisely to avoid cases like this.

Comment: One can restrict to invertible ideals, and in that case, one still obtains I group. But that's a bit like cheating...

Comment: That's not cheating, it's how you define ray class groups.

Comment: What's a free ring $S$ of rang $2$. You mean "a commutative ring which is free of rank 2 as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module"?


Comment: Worst title ever!

Comment: @ Joel : Yes
@ Franz : I can't understand the relation with ray class group !!!


Comment: Franz: Do you mean *ring* class group?

Comment: To emphasize the point raised by David, *every* proper subring $S$ of the integers of a quadratic field, besides the subring ${\mathbf Z}$, is free of rank 2 as a ${\mathbf Z}$-module and contains a non-invertible ideal, so the $S$-ideal classes are not a group under multiplication.